# gwt 2.4.0 blank page for IE only

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Good Afternoon,

I made a small project using GWT 2.4.0, i display well locally in Dev Mode with IE8/IE9, however once i deploy it to a weblogic 10r3 server, the web page is showing as white blank page under all IE browser regardless of version, even for the IE9. while the firefox (version 12+) could display web page without any problem.

I found a fix for IE9 is that when using IE9 press F12 and bring document mode to IE9 mode. however my user is using IE8 and IE8 don't have F12 function (Developer Tools) Bundled, I had to make this gwt app work for IE8. any help is much appreciated.

@update

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

i add X-UA-Compatible IE=8 tag etc to html page. now i am getting error try to display the web page

```
 [ERROR] [dca] - Failed to create an instance of 'com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DatePicker' via deferred binding    
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
 [ERROR] [dca] - Unable to load module entry point class core.client.Dca (see associated exception for details)
 [ERROR] [dca] - Failed to load module 'dca' from user agent 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)' at 127.0.0.1:64353
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is pick, make sure your doc type and meta data are set right, also make sure you have the proper user agent. Also IE Devtoolbar helps to see if the javascript is even getting excuted by inspecting the divs injected into the dynamic iframe.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9

heres your possible settings for user.agent gwt property that should go into your ...gwt.xml file

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml

make sure you can run and view the application in devmode locally in IE before working on deploying to production.

Comment: Hi Kakes, thx for help, i think gwt is try to display the page now. some error encountered, indicating the DatePicker is the source of the problem. what do you think ?

Comment: By the way, this happen on Dev Mode, and if i use F12 to change Doc Mode to IE9, everything works